# Go factory method returns type interface, not the struct which implements the interface

Tags: go, interface, factory-method

I am trying to create a factory method that returns a constructor for a struct that implements some interface.

Here is some sample code that illustrates the pattern I'm using.

```
// Generic Interface
type Foo interface {
    Bar() string
}

type FooConstructor func(name string) Foo

// A struct that implements Foo
type RealFoo struct {
    Name string
}

func (f *RealFoo) Bar() string {
    return f.Name
}

func NewRealFoo(name string) Foo {
    return &RealFoo{Name: name}
}

// Factory method to return some FooConstructor
func FooFactory() FooConstructor {
    // based on some logic, return some Foo constructor
    return NewRealFoo
}

func main() {
    ff := FooFactory()
    f := ff("baz")
    fmt.Println(f.Bar())
    fmt.Println(f.Name)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/0RzXlIGAs8

When I try and access a field on my struct that is not defined in the interface, I get an error:

`f.Name undefined (type Foo has no field or method Name)`

I believe the problem is that my constructor, `func NewRealFoo(name string) Foo` has the interface as the return type, instead of `*RealFoo`. But in order to use it as a type `FooConstructor` for the factory method, the return type must be the `Foo` interface.

How can I fix my code so that I can access the field `f.Name`?

Comment: There is no need to program Java in Go.

Comment: @Volker what would an appropriate design pattern be in Go?

Comment: That is a strange question. Design patterns help implementing stuff which cannot be naturally expressed in a language. Why do you think you need a `FooFactory`? Why do you need to wrap a plain, simple, understandable `NewRealFoo` twice (in FooConstructor and FooFactory)? Most probably there is **no** **need** for it; not not and not in the future. E.g. testing works just fine, even without factories producing constructors.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually returning the `RealFoo` object, but as an implementation of `Foo`.

To get the field of the `RealFoo` struct, use a type assertion:

```
f.(RealFoo).Name
```

or, to avoid panic if it's not a `RealFoo`:

```
if realFoo, ok := f.(RealFoo); ok {
    _ := realFoo.Name
}
```

or a switch over all or some of the possible types of `Foo`

```
switch rf := f.(type) {
case realFoo:
    _ := rf.Name // rf is a realFoo
case unrealFoo:
    _ := rf.ImaginaryName // rf is an unrealFoo
case surrealFoo:
    _ := rf.SurrealName // rf is a surrealFoo
default: 
    // rf is none of the above types
}
```

You could also return a `RealFoo` from `NewRealFoo`, instead of a `Foo`, if you are willing to modify your factory constructor. It will still be valid to use anywhere a `Foo` is expected, since it implements that interface. That's what you are doing that in `NewRealFoo`, when returning a `RealFoo` in a function returning `Foo`.

```
func NewRealFoo(name string) RealFoo {
    return &RealFoo{Name: name}
}
```

Comment: These are very good suggestions, but I am trying to avoid type casting because then I would need to know which concrete implementation was returned from the factory and thus defeats the purpose of the factory method. I think my problem is that I'm trying to access a field, which the interface knows nothing about. If it's a field present on all implementation, I should wrap it in a method, like `f.Name()` and add that to the interface.

Comment: You already have that in `foo.Bar()`. What part of your question did I not answer?